# PyPDF2 creates unreadable PDF

Tags: python, pdf

My code merges two PDFs but in trying to set the desktop of the user as the destination of the new PDF the result is an unreadable PDF.

```
from PyPDF2 import *
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import LETTER
from datetime import datetime
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileMerger
import io
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import os
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.withdraw()\

#CREATE THE CARB PDF PAGE##################################
currentDay = datetime.now().day
currentMonth = datetime.now().month
currentYear = datetime.now().year

c = canvas.Canvas("CARB.pdf", pagesize=LETTER)
c.drawString(10, 170, "TEST")
c.drawString(45, 160, "TEST")
c.drawString(25, 150, "TEST")
c.drawString(50, 140, "___________ MONTH     __________ YEAR")
c.drawString(80, 140, str(currentMonth))
c.drawString(200, 140, str(currentYear))
c.save()
#########################################################

username = os.getenv('username')
packet = io.BytesIO()
filename = askopenfilename()
packet.seek(0)
new_pdf = PdfFileReader(filename)
name = (os.path.basename(filename))
name = name[:-4]

#MERGE THE CREATED PDF WITH THE EXESTING PDF##############
existing_pdf = "CARB.pdf"
f1 = new_pdf
f2 = PdfFileReader(open('carb.pdf', 'rb'))
merger = PdfFileMerger(strict=True)
merger.append(f1)
merger.append(f2)
#merger.write(name + "-CARB.pdf")
output = PdfFileWriter()
outputStream = open("C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Desktop\\" + name + "-CARB.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Comment: Which version of PyPDF2 / report lab are you using?

Comment: Can you share CARB.pdf?

Comment: Please make an minimal complete example. "username = os.getenv('username')" is likely not set on other systems

Comment: I guess the tkinter stuff can be removed?

Comment: Hi Prometheus. You need to make a copy of this program and delete any line that does not help illustrate the problem (delete, don’t comment-out). In this case a few lines that manually create a PDF, don’t even use the draw code, just c = Canvas(“test.pdf”, …) then c.save(). Then another few lines to use existing_pdf or PdfFileReader to do the merge. Please make your code as small, simple, and overall easy for us to read as you can. Thank you.